# WMV support in Android code

Tags: android

I have a basic 7 inch tab - which claims to support wmv and runs Android Froyo 2.2 . But none of my wmv files work even when reduced to the required resolution. Googling gives me trying RockPlayer which does play some wmv files. But when I try to play them via code it does not work. It gives me error(1,-4) and shows this video cannot be played. What do I have to do to play WMV files via code. Is there any codec that exists that I can port with my application so that it can play wmv files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think android doesnot support wmv files .It is supported only in windows .

Comment: Thanks. Is there any codec that you are aware that I can port with my application so that it can play wmv files ?

Answer (score 0):

WMV files can be played in android as long as the metadata contains the framerate.  try editing unplayable wmv files using any video conversion tools and set the framerate.  you should be able to play it.

Comment: All videos have frame rate meta data - android does not play any wmv natively . Can you please elaborate what you are saying

Comment: You are right, android by default doesn't support WMV.  but if a device claims that it can play WMV, then a codec for WMV should come with that device and the reason why other WMV files fail to play because the metadata of that WMV file doesn't contain the framerate.